# Microsoft Graph API - How to create multiple users at once

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I know that the json format for creating 1 user is:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
   }
}
```

Is there a way to create multiple users at once with 1 API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Graph [$batch](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching) feature to bundle up to 20 requests in a single call.

Have a look at this sample app that implements batching and parallelization to get more throughput through Graph.

A method that creates a lot of users:
https://github.com/piotrci/Microsoft-Graph-Efficient-Operations/blob/babe86caa9f53f15c565469eed9a2714b5dff24c/Microsoft-Graph-Efficient-Operations/ScenarioImplementations/TestDataSetup.cs#L16

More info: https://github.com/piotrci/Microsoft-Graph-Efficient-Operations/blob/master/README.md